# Redirect API call fetches from Service Worker

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

This is a really annoying issue. I am using a third party login in my application. When a user logins in through the third party, it redirects an api call to the server.

ex: /api/signin/github?code=test&state=test

For some strange reason this API call is getting fetched from the service worker instead on the server which handles the login logic.

ex:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your service worker's `fetch` event handler, it's hard to say exactly what code is responsible for that.

In general, though, if there are URLs for which you want to tell the service worker never to respond to, you can just avoid calling `event.respondWith(...)` when they trigger a `fetch`. There are lots of ways to avoid doing that, but an early `return` is straightforward:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  if (url.pathname === '/api/signin/github') {
    // By returning without calling event.respondWith(),
    // the request will be handled by the normal browser
    // network stack.
    return;
  }

  // Your fetch event response generation logic goes here.
  event.respondWith(...);
});
```